# How to upload image to EC2 through a python-flask web app running in the same EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have Python-Flask web-app running inside EC2 which performs a binary image classification. The web-app has a UI which allows the user to select the image.

**High Level Architecture:**

```
 1. Select the file to 
    be uploaded using the
    web-app UI

 2. Press the "Classify" button.

 3. Image gets uploaded to EC2.

 4. Perform image classification
    and return the results.

 5. Delete the image.
```

Could you please guide me on how to upload the image located on my machine to EC2 (Step 3) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you press the "Classify" button, your form on your web-app will pass a multipart form data to the flask application. Then within Python, you'll intercept that and save the file.

Python has a great intro on this here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/